# Vue mounted event not executing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to build a page where a variable should be set as soon as the page is loaded. I placed my method and tried debugging it repeatedly with no result at all, then I tried to just print a string to the console at `mounted` and nothing happened either... I'm not sure if I'm missing something.

I scaffold my project using Vue CLI and at the moment, in the following code, I'm going to insert changes to the `HelloWorld.vue` from the template

I have added a button as a check as well,

```
<button onclick="foo">foo</button>
```

the script section of the page looks like this:

```
<script>
    export default {
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
        },
        methods: {
            mounted: function() {
                console.log("Mounted!")
            },
            foo: function() {
                console.log("button")
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

expected behaviour is to get "Mounted!" on the console upon save and refresh, and "button" whenever I click the button.
I get nothing when the page is displayed, and only "button" appears whenever I click the button. 
Is `mounted` the wrong function to use here or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Ah. It's a simple and common mistake people do. Here is how you should actually write mounted.

```
<script>
    export default {
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
        },
        methods: {
            foo: function() {
                console.log("button")
            }
        },
        mounted: function() {
            console.log("Mounted!")
        },
    }
</script>
```

mounted should be at the same level with methods, data or computed. Not inside methods.

That's all, it should work now.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 5):

Not the issue here, but I experienced the same thing when I forgot to include the closing `</script>` tag.  Just in case it saves someone else a bit of head scratching...

Answer (score 2):

Not the issue here too, but i got the same thing when i wrote by mistake two mounted functions.

Comment: This answer could have been submitted as a comment to the originators question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30065507)